# Creating a VFP that act as a splash screen and opens up the App Launcher

Tags: visualforce, community, customer-community

I am working on a custom requirement and need help on creating a VisualForce Page that act as a splash screen and opens up the App Launcher if the user agrees to the terms and conditions on the Splash screen

Comment: Have you tried anything? Are you just asking us to write the page for you?

Comment: I am checking is the functionality can be implemented or it is out of the box

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need are [Login Flows](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Login-Flows). You will have to figure out how to put one together to suit your needs, but it does what you want. You might be able to customize one of the below.

> ### Login Flow samples
>
> You can use this unmanaged package to install different login flow samples into your Salesforce organization:
>
> [Install Login Flow samples](https://login.salesforce.com/packaging/installPackage.apexp?p0=04to0000000WA6J)
>
> This package contains the following samples:
>
> - Email Confirmation - Send email with a verification code
> - SF-TOTP - Time-based One-Time Password two-factor authentication
> - Conditional Two-Factor- Skip Two-factor authentication for users who come from a trusted IP address
> - Identity Confirmation - Confirm the user identity using email and/or two-factor authentication
> - **Accept Terms of Service - Have the user agree to to terms before continuing**